# pcre-config error on building Apr-util 1.6.x

Tags: apache-httpd, apr, pcre

I have a working setup on my CentOS system that takes Apache HTTPD, and the supporting libraries such as PCRE, Apr, Apr-util, etc. This is done using a shell script that applies custom patches to the source, configures, builds and installs these libraries using MAKE.

Each of these libraries are built using the prescribed steps, there's nothing different being done other than adding patches to the src.

The trouble started with latest updates to Apr-util (1.6.x). While running the Apr-util config I'm getting this error:

```
checking for pcre-config... false
configure: error: pcre-config for libpcre not found. PCRE is required and available from http://pcre.org
```

I have pcre installed in my system, but it's not able to pick it up, for some reason.

I've followed the following steps for installing pcre:

```
./configure --prefix=$PCRE_ROOT --enable-utf --disable-cpp
make
make install
```

I get a positive response when I issue `make test`

**Is there any variation to the latest apr-util configuration?**

Also, I'm aware of the fact that apr-util 1.6.x onwards the **expat library** has been decoupled with the bundle. I'm trying to build & install expat as well, but I'm not sure if this could be causing any issue.

Comment: You are saying you have a highly customised compiled environment, and expect people to guess what you have done, that´s it? I would advise at least describing how you have installed PCRE, and which distro you are using.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I was hoping to see if anyone has faced issues while configuring apr-util
Anyways, thanks for the advise, I'm updating the question in a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the fix for this issue. We need to mention `--with-pcre=<PCRE ROOT>` with the `configure` command for APR.

Pls note:
1. This isn't mandatory in case you're using apr-1.5.x
2. If you execute `./configure --help` from APR source directory it doesn't list out the `--with-pcre` option